# if statement inside html email python

Tags: python, mime

I am using MIME Multipart to compose an email in HTML and sending using smtplib and would like to include a sentence only if a condition evaluates to true. Basically something like

```
html = """\
    <html>
      <body>
        Hi {name}<br>
        Hope you are doing well.
           **<% if {empanelled}: %>**
                <br> We are already empanelled with your company<br>

      </body>
    </html>
    """.format(name=firstname, empanelled = empanelled)
```

If we are empanelled (value = 1) the sentence following this should be written else if value = 0, should not appear
. Any pointers to how I can do this with python will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is `empanelled` a Python variable?

Comment: You should use a proper templating solution, such as Jinja2.

Comment: Yes, empanelled is a python variable

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As mentioned, you should using something like [Jinja2](http://jinja.pocoo.org). However, unless I am misunderstanding your question, you have the `empanelled` variable in python. why not jus evaluate the conditional in python like this:

```
html = """\
    <html>
      <body>
        Hi {name}<br>
        Hope you are doing well.
             {additional_message}
      </body>
    </html>
    """

if empanelled:
    return html.format(name=firstname, additional_message="<br> We are already empanelled with your company<br>")
else:
    return html.format(name=firstname,additional_message="")
```

Although, some templating language approach would still be better.

Comment: Thanks for the solutions and the pointers. This solves it neatly :)

Comment: Awesome!, @AdityaGanguli please accept the answer if it works for you!

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
    if empanelled: 
        empanelledtxt= "<br> We are already empanelled with your company<br>"
    else:
        empanelledtxt=""
    html=html = """\
        <html>
          <body>
            Hi {name}<br>
            Hope you are doing well.""".format(name=firstname)+empanelledtxt+"""</body></html>"""`
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Used something similar to ur answer.